# How to set an environment variable from .env file that references other environment variables

Tags: shell, environment-variables, zsh

I have a file called `.env` with environment variables:

```
MY_VAR="a value"
A_VAR=3
ANOTHER_VAR=${PWD}
```

I use this file to set the variables for a node.js script before its execution like this:

```
env $(cat .env | xargs) node script.js
```

This works fine as long as the values in the .env file are static, in this example here though I would like `${PWD}` for `ANOTHER_VAR` to expand into the current working directory (which is available in the PWD environment variable, I have checked that).

If I try it with

```
env -vS "ANOTHER_VAR=${PWD}" printenv ANOTHER_VAR
```

it works fine, but somehow when I load the variables from the file with cat & xargs the ${PWD} doesn't get expanded.

So when I try this

```
env $(cat .env | xargs) printenv ANOTHER_VAR
```

it returns `${PWD}` instead of (for example) `/Users/myuser/some/folder`.

I have tried everything I can imagine and googled around but I just cannot get env to actually interpret the `{$PWD}`, how can I load environment variables from a .env file such that the values can reference other environment variables?

I am on OS X 12.4 and my shell is zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)

Comment: Why isn't `script.js` using [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to process the file itself?

Answer (score -1):

Finally got it working thanks to the hint from @kvantour, this does the trick for me:

```
bash -c 'set -a; source .env; printenv ANOTHER_VAR'
```

The env variable is only available for the printenv command.

Comment: Beware: a `.env` file is *not* a shell script, and sourcing it with the shell may have different results than letting a dotenv parser process it. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#user-content-what-rules-does-the-parsing-engine-follow.

Comment: Example: `JSON={"foo": "bar"}` is a valid assignment in a `.env` file, but a syntax error in `zsh`. Bash will *likely* fail with a command-not-found error on `bar}`.

Comment: I see, thanks for these hints @chepner. What would be your proposed solution for this situation then?